# How do I find documents using multiple conditions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have looked at other posts and none seem to address what I'm trying to do. I need to create a query that searches for all records that have type_ids in an array, AND belong to the current logged in user. Here is what I have:

Query:

```
app.post('/photos', function(req, res) {
    Photos
        .find({
            'type_id': { $in: req.body.type_ids },
            $and : {'groups.users': { $in: req.user._id }}
        })
        .select('name size')
        .exec(function(err, data) {
            return res.json(data);
        });
});
```

Schema:

```
var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    size : String,
    type_id : String,
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    groups : {
        users : [],
        other : []
    }
});
```

The only thing I can get to work is the following query:

```
app.post('/photos', function(req, res) {
    Photos
        .find({'type_id': { $in: req.body.type_ids }})
        .select('name size')
        .exec(function(err, data) {
            return res.json(data);
        });
});
```

But, obviously this won't work because I only want those results for a particular user. The line `$and : {'groups.users': { $in: req.user._id }}` clearly isn't working, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The "and" operator is implied in queries, so `$and` is rarely necessary.  You can just use:

```
{
    'type_id': { $in: req.body.type_ids },
    'groups.users': { $in: req.user._id }
}
```

Although, based on the name of the variable, the second line sounds wrong - you probably want just `'groups.users': req.user._id` (you should drop the `$in`).

Finally, the way to use `$and` is by giving it an array:

```
{
    '$and': [
        { 'type_id': { $in: req.body.type_ids } },
        { 'groups.users': { $in: req.user._id } }
    ]
}
```

But like I said, its unnecessary here.

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't working. I tried ``'groups.users': { $in: req.user._id }`` and ``'groups.users': req.user._id``, but neither worked. If I remove this line from the query, then I get data back, it just isn't filtered by `user._id``.

Comment: To remove doubt about what you're trying to do, could you give some actual sample documents that do and don't match a particular example of the sort of query that you want to do?

Comment: @ChrisPaterson It sounds like the variable `req.user._id` isn't what you'd expect it to be.